# How to soft delete records in Laravel and Eloquent

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a view that shows the data pulled out of the database and the client wants to actually delete some of the records on the view with out actually having to delete the record from the database.I am a newbie in Laravel can anyone suggest the approach I may have to follow to acheive this??

Comment: So create a flag `deleted` (for example) and select only rows with `deleted = 0`, and when deleting set that flag to `1`

Answer (score 4):

You want to use [soft deletes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#soft-deleting). This will add a `deleted_at` column to your table and set the timestamp that the record was marked as deleted, without actually deleting the record. In your schemas, simply add the following  to any table you need soft deleted:

```
$table->softDeletes();
```

Your model will need to use the `SoftDeletes` trait, as well:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class MyModel extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
}
```

The `trashed` method will show whether or not the record has been deleted, and the `withTrashed` method is used to return results that include deleted records.